# Sum all values in column B for each unique value in column A using vba

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason I think I am making this harder than it should be, but I am trying to do exactly what the title says. That is, when a person's name appears in one column I want to start a running count/sum of the values in another column throughout a list. For example, in the screenshot provided I would have gathered the following names and sums/values:

- Mary, 5
- George, 9
- Nick, 5
- Vani, 1
- Wes, 7

I want to create a bar chart with each person and their total but at the moment it's showing each entry individually on the chart (for example George would have 5 separate entries on the bar chart with values 3,1,1,3,1). All the names are also within a single Named Range as well if that helps.

Lastly, I want to do all this through VBA. The code now just simply looks like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'SettingsSummary'!$D$3:$D$72,'SettingsSummary'!$E$3:$E$72")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
```

[image]

Comment: In what columns are the values to be processed?  From your picture (without the column headers) it is not possible to deduce that... If I will prepare an answer for columns A:B, should it be OK?

Comment: In principle, a dictionary should be used in order to deal with the summing per unique value and then place in arrays the keys and items. Then feed the chart with those arrays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It assumes that the Names are in column A:A and their values in B:B. It skips the keys "-" and add zero in case of value being "-":

```
Sub UniqueValsInChart()
  Dim shT As Worksheet, ch As Chart, lastRow As Long
  Dim arrY, arrX, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set shT = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  lastRow = shT.Range("A" & shT.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arrX = shT.Range("A4:B" & lastRow).value         'put the range in a array
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")    'needed for the next step
  
  On Error Resume Next
   shT.ChartObjects("MyChartXY").Delete             'in case of running again the sub...
  On Error GoTo 0
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrX)
    If arrX(i, 1) <> "-" Then
        If Not dict.Exists(arrX(i, 1)) Then
            dict(arrX(i, 1)) = arrX(i, 2)                    'create the unique keys
        Else
            'add the values for the same key if they are not "-":
            dict(arrX(i, 1)) = dict(arrX(i, 1)) + IIf(arrX(i, 2) = "-", 0, arrX(i, 2))
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  arrX = dict.Keys: arrY = dict.items                   'extract the necessary arrays
  
  Set ch = shT.ChartObjects.Add(left:=shT.Range("E4").left, _
            top:=shT.Range("E4").top, width:=250, height:=250).Chart
  With ch
    .Parent.name = "MyChartXY"
    .ChartType = xlBarClustered
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Unique values..."
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arrY   'feed it with the array elements
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = arrX           'feed it with the array elements
  End With
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly as I needed it but only after I edited a line above to be this:                   
 `If (arrX(i, 1) <> "-") And IsNumeric(arrX(i, 2)) Then`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a Pivot table, not a chart.
A Pivot table with rows=Name and Value=Sum of

Comment: The blanks would preclude this from being used in a pivot table.